Can I call an anonymous function inside a <scrip> tag linked to an external js file?
HTML File(firstHTML.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p id="demo">First Paragraph</p>
<p id="demo2">Second Paragraph should be something different</p>
<script src="myScript.js">
    show3();
</script>
</body>
</html>

JavaScript File(myScript.js)
let show3 = function() {
document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML='I am trying to change the second paragraph using an anonymous function in an external JS file';
};
I was expecting for the show() function to run since it's below the  tag. I am still learning about javascript scope so it's entirely possible that anonymous functions don't have a global scale and so my function won't run but why is my question. Thank you all in advance.

You can't put your own code in a <script> tag with a src.  The tag has to be empty.  So, just add a second <script> tag with YOUR code.

The issue was caused by calling show3() before the external JavaScript file had been loaded and parsed.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p id="demo">First Paragraph</p>
<p id="demo2">Second Paragraph should be something different</p>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>
<script>
    // Wait for the DOM content to fully load
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        show3(); // Safe to call now
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>




think of it like this.
when you put src attribut to script tag
all the content in the script tag will be replaced with code in source file.
example:
❌ wrong way
script.js
console.log("hellow fron inside script.js file");

 const show = function(){
    console.log("show function called");
}

inside index.html
    <script src="script.js"> show() </script>

// above script tag will be interpreted as

   <script> 
console.log("hellow fron inside script.js file"); 

const show = function(){
       console.log("show function called");
    }
</script>
    
   

✅ rights way
index.html
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script> show()</script>

or call show() function inside script.js also
script.js
     console.log("hellow fron inside script.js file");

    const show = function(){
       console.log("show function called");
     }
   show();


above script tag will be interpreted as - except ... it won't, because you can't have src AND inline script on the same script tag

Have you run it ? Because it is working fine when. I runes it.

Yeah, what Jaromanda X said. It won't interpret it that way because it doesn't allow for code to be inside a 
there what I mean was that only code on  src file will get executed , and not the code in between script tag when src and code between script tag both are written

Understood, that certainly makes more sense.

@PriyanshBisht - It is perfectly obvious I wasn't talking about the FIXED code with TWO <script> tags, I was commenting on your incorrect assertion of what the OP's code would be "interpreted as" ... if you can't understand what I wrote, then it seems you don't even know what YOU wrote

@Yahya Hassan - now it's right, right?

Answer : Yes
explanation
when you use the src with the script tag its actually import javaScript you write in the file inside the script tag.
